# 'font not found' on iPhone/iPad

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, fonts, webrick

I'm working on a [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) app, which, if you're not familiar with the platform, is a static website generator that runs on Ruby. It uses a webrick server for development.

So, I'm also using [fontello](http://fontello.com/) to load some icon glyphs.

Now, when I have the server running, and I load the page on a PC (windows or linux, various browsers) everything works fine.

When I load the page on an iDevice, I get the following warnings

```
[2016-05-27 22:54:10] ERROR `/font/fontello.svg' not found.
[2016-05-27 22:54:10] ERROR `/font/fontello.woff' not found.
[2016-05-27 22:54:11] ERROR `/font/fontello.ttf' not found.
[2016-05-27 22:54:12] ERROR `/font/fontello.svg' not found.
```

Now, the weird part is, the fonts load fine. The page looks just like it should on the iDevice. Which seems odd. If it can't load the font, why is the font displaying?

I'm tempted to just ignore the warnings, but then I'm worried the page will load slower if there are 404's.

Again, the error only appears on iDevices. Same application generates no errors on desktop or android.

Any ideas?

Comment: So your icons are showing regardless of these warnings?

Comment: Yes. The fonts are loaded and look fine.